# Como é atualizada/incluida uma página em PHP via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Comecei a pensar em utilizar AJAX em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, mas encontrei alguns problemas com o mesmo. Gostaria de entender como ele funciona, para aproveitar ao máximo esta "ferramenta".

Não tive problemas ao acrescentar páginas estáticas ou com scripts simples em php.

Tenho, até então, em minha mente que a função envia a requisição para o servidor, armazena a resposta em uma variável e nós decidimos o que fazer com ela.

```
$('li > a').click(function(evt){

evt.preventDefault();

var href  = $(this).attr('href');
var pages = "includes/pages.php?page=" + href;
$.ajax(pages, {
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#content').fadeOut();
  },
  success: function(response){
    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Minha maior dúvida sobre a inclusão/update de arquivos na página via AJAX é sobre includes e requires.

```
<?php

$page = @$_GET['page'];

switch ($page) {
    case 'home':
        acoInclude('home.php');
        break;

    case 'ceps':
        acoInclude('ceps.php');
        break;

    case 'clientes':
        acoInclude('clients.php');
        break;

    default:
        acoInclude('home.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

O arquivo php em questão possui uma função personalizada (`acoInclude()`) que está dentro do arquivo `primfunctions.php`, dentro de `functions.php` que por sua vez está incluído no index.

Basicamente: `index.php <-> functions.php <-> primfunctions.php`

Ao executar o script, me é retornado um fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function acoInclude() in C:\wamp64\www\gn\sistema\includes\pages.php on line 7
```

Mas se eu incluir o arquivo `primfunctions.php`diretamente no `pages.php` — para isso usei a seguinte lógica: isso (AJAX) deve funcionar tipo um iframe, e um script deve ser independente de outro — recebo mais um fatal error

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare acoInclude() (previously declared in C:\wamp64\www\gn\sistema\includes\primfunctions.php:16) in C:\wamp64\www\gn\sistema\includes\primfunctions.php on line 18
```

Então ficam as perguntas: como os scripts em PHP são incluídos via AJAX? Por que meu script está com estes erros? Como solucioná-los de maneira proveitosa para a aprendizagem?

EDIT: Função `acoInclude`

```
function acoInclude($page){
    include('/pages/'.$page);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

script PHP e Ajax não estão relacionados.
Podes pensar no Ajax como uma "visita" do browser, que chama um ficheiro PHP e devolve a resposta que este lhe dá, como se fosse um utilizador.

Portanto os erros de PHP que tens não são relacionados com Ajax e nem podem ser resolvidos por ele.

O que fazer então?
Os erros que tens acontecem porque estás a chamar uma função que não está defenida no PHP. Para a defenir tens de incluir o(s) ficheiro(s) que contêm essa função.

Assim tens de colocar no teu ficheiro PHP, antes desse `switch`:

```
require_once('primfunctions.php'); // corrige o caminho se não for este
```

assim o erro deve desaparecer. Depois disso presumo que essa função `acoInclude('home.php');` retorne HTML, nesse caso deves ter um `echo` antes, para ela de facto mostrar o resultado a quem estiver à procura dele. Um browser ou o Ajax:

```
echo acoInclude('home.php');
```